# Is Unity IAP collecting card info?

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, privacy-policy

I am currently creating a privacy policy and I came across a page asking for information about the game I'm making. Other than having unity IAP services, it does not have any ads or anything that asks for information. However I am confused if the IAP service will store and collect credit card info, is this the case?

[Collecting information page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCoVf.png)

Comment: IAP uses the payment method the user has setup with whatever app store is appropriate for their platform.

Comment: so if its on google play, that means it doesn't collect information?

Comment: Maybe take a look at [Unitys privacy policy landing page](https://unity.com/legal/privacy-policy).